# Export of user information from AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

I'm looking to export the following information from AD:

```
First Name
Last Name
Login Name
Creation Date
Description
Office
Street
City
Zip Code
Country
```

Also, if users are expired or disabled, they should be excluded.

I have been trying to figure out how to get it using PS but it does not work.

Rgds
Claus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet (which is part of the Active Directory module).

[Get-ADUser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx)

You should be able to pull all the info you're looking for with the `-Properties` parameter, and exclude expired and disabled users with the `-Filter` parameter.

For example:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true -and PasswordExpired -eq $false} -Properties "streetaddress","postalcode"
```

would return the `streetaddress` and `postalcode` parameters of all users who are enabled and who's passwords haven't expired.

From there, it's just a matter of selecting the properties you want and exporting the data.